# Jquery - Trying to hide and show bunch of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having slight problem with my jquery code. I'm new to Jquery, so please help me improve my code. Well I'm trying to hide and show this 4 images. Let me elaborate it a bit:

1. I created this 4 images (put side by side)
2. When one clicked it should expand and hides the other
3. When the expanded click it should return to its normal dimension and shows the other
4. Then it should be repeated

My code seems to work on the first go, but it messes up on the second run (the images doesn't behave like what i envision them to behave)

Here is my code:
http://codepen.io/sallyiee/pen/onkKs

Comment: Put your code here at SO. Question should be complete. There should not be a case for people to visit some offsite resource.

Comment: Try to use toggleClass toggle for hiding and showing.

Comment: Yap i got it :) Thanks heaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code with `toggleClass` and `toggle` metods:

```
$(".showcase" ).on("click", "img", function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
    $(this).siblings().toggle("fast"); 
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mlBEI

Comment: Yes, you are welcome. Your problem was, that you don't have `.expand` elements initially to bind click events to. In this case you could use event delegation `$('.showcase').on('click', '.expand', function() {...})`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".showcase img" ).click(function(e) {
    if( $(this).hasClass('expand')) {
      $(this).removeClass("expand").addClass("normal").show("fast");
      $(this).siblings().show("fast");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("expand").removeClass("normal");
      $(this).siblings().hide("fast");
    }
  });
```

http://codepen.io/tamilcselvan/pen/HpbiK

Comment: You need to add `$(this).removeClass("normal")` in else part